# Python HTTP Server to download files remotely

Tags: python

I want to make a python HTTP Server that runs on my machine, it will listen for me to send it urls and then it will take that url and download it to the computer.

Example:

- PC1 has Downloader.py running with a simple interface, an input and a submit button.
- I send "https://mega.nz/file/XXXXXXXX#XXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXX-XXX" to PC1 from my phone.
- Downloader.py receives the mega url and starts downloading the file in the background.

Ideally this would be non-blocking so if I send 2 links one after the other it wouldn't wait for the first to finish before downloading the second.

I already have the download functions but I'm not sure how to put it together with an HTTP Server.

subprocess? threading? multiprocessing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you familiar with python, it can be easily done with [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html).